# Android Toolbar doesn't show

Tags: java, android, toolbar

I'm developing a native android app.
It's contains a toolbar and this is xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:titleTextColor="@color/maroon"
        app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<include layout="@layout/activity_home" />
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_dialer"
    android:background="@color/maroon"
    android:visibility="gone" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Activity code :

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

on smartphone tooblar work correctly, on tablet (4.x) doesn't show.
Any idea?

Comment: app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle" remove this

Comment: no, this solution doesn't work.

Comment: with android 5.x everything work correctly, instead with 4.x no. I think that the problem is not smartphone or tablet, but version, nobody knows why?